# Zend Framework 2 - Hide login link when logged in and vice versa for logout

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm pretty new to ZF2 and I'm trying to find a simple way to allow the login link to be hidden within the view a user has been logged in, and show it again when the user logs out. I have taken a look at ZF2's ACL examples, but I am still a little confused and I am unsure if this is actually what is needed to achieve such a simple thing.

If somebody could share some knowledge on how this is done, I would be eternally greatful. Thank you

Comment: Lot's of information missing. What are you using for authentication, selfmade? ZfcUser? - How are you rendering out the login-link? Zend\Navigation? Simple Html?

Comment: Sorry Sam, I am just trying to my head around the ways of ZF2 so I am using a selfmade Authentication and simple html navigation. However, I have taken a look at ZF2 navigation, and could implement that easily. Thanks

Comment: Well if you have your own authentication, you should have an authentication service. Then you'd build a view-helper, which has access to the service. And then something like `if($this->myAuthService()->isLogin()) { echoNavigation(); }`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll look into this and get back to you if there are any problems if that's okay with you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Sam, I've found a nice workaround which is similar to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard [Identity view helper](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/View/Helper/Identity.php) that can help you with this. This will work out of the box if you add your authentication service to the service manager, for instance in your module's `config/module.config.php` like this:

```
/* Some configuration omitted */

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService' => function($sm) {
            $authService = new \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService();
            $authService->setStorage(new \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session('user', 'details'));

            return $authService;
        },
    ),
);
```

Then you can do like this in your view script:

```
if ($this->identity() == null) {
    // User is not logged in; show login link here
}

else {
    // User is logged in; show profile link here or do nothing
}
```